# How To Set Limit Table Row SQL?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

How to set limit table row in SQL Server?

I want to set limit of my table rows to 100 rows only.

So when the table have more than 100 rows, I want to delete first row then add new row to last row (100).

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing that i can assure you..

1. Create a trigger that if > 100 then delete first record record.

see [here](http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=123439) as your guide.

Answer (score 2):

I think you hv to do two things
i) Create Trigger

```
declare @MaxRowLimit int=5
declare @t table(col1 int)
insert into @t values(1),(2),(3),(4),(5)

insert into @t VALUES(12)

;With CTE as
(


select top (@MaxRowLimit) col1 

from @t t1
order by t1.col1 desc
)
,CTE1 as(
select * from @t t
where not exists
(select  col1 

from cte t1 where t.col1=t1.col1
)
)
delete from cte1
select * from @t
```

ii) If it is bulk insert then,you hv to do manipulation before bulk insert.
like if bulk insert count is greater than 100 then sort and keep last 100 rows and remove rest rows.